# Stored procedure to unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures, unpivot

I have a table with these columns:

```
surname  name  birthdate  id_doc  role   01         02       ... 50
Vardy    Jack  19870215    1234   'emp'  20200110   20200527     20200610
```

Where fields from 01 to 50 are dates. I need to have a table like this:

```
surname  name  birthdate  id_doc  role   title_code   data
Vardy    Jack  19870215    1234   'emp'     01        20200110   
Vardy    Jack  19870215    1234   'emp'     02        20200527     
....
```

Where title code should be the column name from 01 to 50, data should be the value of that column in mytable

I did this stored procedure by looking in older questions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @UnpivotList NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
    SELECT @UnpivotList = CONCAT(@UnpivotList, ',(''', c.name, ''', fe.', c.name, ')')
    FROM 
       sys.columns c
    WHERE 
       c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
       AND c.column_id > 5;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT(N'
    SELECT 
       fe.surname,
       fe.name,
       fe.birthdate,
       fe.id_doc,
       fe.role,
       ul.title_code,
       ul.Data
    FROM 
       mytable fe
       CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ', STUFF(@UnpivotList, 1, 1, ''), N') ul (title_code, Data)');
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

but I'm getting a syntax error near `'.01'`. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the column names: since they start with a digit, you need to quote the identifiers - in SQL Server, you need to use square brackets. You can take care of that this in the first query.

```
SELECT @UnpivotList = CONCAT(@UnpivotList, ',(''', c.name, ''', fe.[', c.name, '])')
FROM sys.columns c                                               --^    here    ^ --
WHERE 
   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
   AND c.column_id > 5;
```